# Permission Denied for lo_import

Tags: postgresql, permissions, psql

I have the following code that runs to set up my database, and I get an error when running the 3rd command `psql:db/seed_data.sql:3: ERROR:  permission denied for function lo_import`

setup.sh

```sh
psql -h localhost -p 5432 \
  --dbname=postgres \
  --file=db/db_setup.sql 

psql -h localhost -p 5432 \
  --username=admin \
  --dbname=mydb \
      --file=db/schema.sql

psql -h localhost -p 5432 \
  --username=admin \
  --dbname=mydb \
  --file=db/seed_data.sql
```

db_setup.sql grants all permissions to my admin user

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;

CREATE ROLE admin WITH LOGIN;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb to admin;
```

seed_data.sql contains the following command

```
INSERT INTO mydb(name, raster) VALUES('Herald', lo_import('/Users/myname/this-folder/some-image-name.png'));
```

When I run that INSERT INTO command manually from the PQSL command line, it succeeds, but when I try to run it in the context of the setup.sh script, it fails.

I am confused because the user should have all the permissions to insert into the database.

The file permissions for `some-image-name.png` are `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: Read [lo functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/lo-funcs.html). In particular; "The server-side lo_import and lo_export functions behave considerably differently from their client-side analogs. These two functions read and write files in the server's file system, using the permissions of the database's owning user. Therefore, by default their use is restricted to superusers. "

Comment: Thanks! Solution (this is just a local toy app) was to do `ALTER ROLE admin SUPERUSER;` in my db_setup.sql

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Sounds like a useful answer?

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation [lo functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/lo-funcs.html). In particular:

> The server-side lo_import and lo_export functions behave considerably differently from their client-side analogs. These two functions read and write files in the server's file system, using the permissions of the database's owning user. Therefore, by default their use is restricted to superusers.